# Could not find module 'Q'. Platform Windows. VS2015 RTM

Tags: visual-studio-cordova

I am getting this error when building for platform 'windows':

------ Building platform: windows
  Debug
  ------ Build configuration options: --debug
  Running command: C:\Projects......\platforms\windows\cordova\build.bat --debug --archs=arm --phone
MSBUILD : cordova-build error BLD401: Error : BLD00401 : Could not find module 'Q'.

Answer (score 2):

Clearing cache and reinstall vs-tac didn't help.
Deleting platforms folder fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

First thing to try with this error is to clear the cache, and re-install vs-tac, if necessary: https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/dn771551(v=vs.140).aspx#vstac